# New Access record added via Excel VBA, but not showing up in the database

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ado

I'm writing a utility in Excel that will gather some data from ini files then write it into an Access database as a new record. I've tried multiple ways of doing this, but with no luck.

I've tried various combinations of connection and recordset, but whatever I try I just get "Error 3709 The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context". The following code gives me this error:

```
Private Sub WriteButton_Click()
    
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim r As Long
    Dim PNum As String
    Dim Multi As String
    Dim strAddNew As String
     
    'Declare variables for cell contents
    Dim OrderNum As Long
     Dim OrderQty As Integer
     Dim AssyOps As String
    
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
     
    OrderNum = Range("C2")
    OrderQty = Range("C4")
    AssyOps = Range("F11")
    
    If BOMT <> "" Then
        Call WriteBOMTime
        'nc = GetPrivateProfileString("BOM Time", Part, "Time Not Found", BOMT, Len(BOMT), "R:\VAB\Weetech Reports\ini Files\LogPrep.ini") 'Read Part Number from Orders.ini
        If BOMT = "" Then
            MsgBox "BOM Time not written to ini file.", vbExclamation, "NOT WRITTEN"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "BOM Time not found.", vbExclamation, "VALUE NOT FOUND"
    End If
    
    Comment = Range("C18")
    Status = "Pass"
    LogTime = Range("F3")
    LogDate = Range("E3")
    Funct = FunctionBox.Value
    
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=S:\Test Yield - Failure Database\New Database\Data\Test Fault Log_be.accdb"
    rs.Open
    rs.AddNew
    rs![Order] = OrderNum
    rs![Qty] = OrderQty
    rs![Operator] = AssyOps
    rs.Update
     
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
     
    rs = Nothing
    cn = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

After a lot of searching I've finally found a version of this that runs without errors and seems to be working:

```
Private Sub WriteButton_Click()

    'Declaring the necessary variables.
    Dim accessFile  As String
    Dim accessTable As String
    Dim sht         As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow     As Long
    Dim lastColumn  As Integer
    Dim con         As Object
    Dim rs          As Object
    Dim sql         As String
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim j           As Integer
     
    'Declare variables for cell contents
    Dim OrderNum As Long, OrderQty As Integer, AssyOps As String, TestOps As String, TestUnit As String, MultiQty As Integer, TotalQty As Integer, SerialLo As Long, SerialHi As Long, TestQty As Integer, TstQMult As Integer, TstSerLo As Long, TstSerHi As Long, TestTime As Integer, SetupTime As String, Funct As String, FLogTime As String, LogDate As String, Comment As String, Status As String, SetTime As String, LogTime As String
     
    OrderNum = Range("C2")
    Part = Range("C3")
    'MsgBox "Part Number: " & Part
    OrderQty = Range("C4")
    AssyOps = Range("F11")
    TestOps = Range("F13")
    TestUnit = Range("C9")
    MultiQty = Range("C5")
    TotalQty = Range("C6")
    SerialLo = Range("C7")
    SerialHi = Range("C8")
    TestQty = Range("C11")
    TstQMult = Range("C12")
    TstSerLo = Range("C13")
    TstSerHi = Range("C14")
    TestTime = Range("C15")
    BOMT = Range("C16")
    'MsgBox "BOM Time: " & BOMT
    SetTime = Range("C17")
            
    'Disable the screen flickering.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    accessFile = "R:\VAB\Weetech Reports\Auto\Amazon\Test Fault Log_be.accdb"
         
    'Ensure that the Access file exists.
    If FileExists(accessFile) = False Then
        MsgBox "The Access file doesn't exist!", vbCritical, "Invalid Access file path"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Set the name of the table you want to add the data.
    accessTable = "tableTestYield"
                
    'Set the worksheet that contains the data.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Yield")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "The given worksheet does not exist!", vbExclamation, "Invalid Sheet Name"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Err.Clear
        
    'Create the ADODB connection object.
    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    
    'Check if the object was created.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "The connection was not created!", vbCritical, "Connection Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Err.Clear
    
    'Open the connection.
    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & accessFile
    
    'Create the SQL statement to retrieve the table data (the entire table).
    sql = "SELECT * FROM " & accessTable
    
    'Create the ADODB recordset object.
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    'Check if the object was created.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set con = Nothing
        MsgBox "The recordset was not created!", vbCritical, "Recordset Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Err.Clear
             
    'Set the necessary recordset properties.
    rs.CursorType = 1   'adOpenKeyset on early binding
    rs.LockType = 3     'adLockOptimistic on early binding
        
    'Open the recordset.
    rs.Open sql, con
    
    'Add the records from Excel to Access.
    rs.AddNew
    rs![Order] = OrderNum
    rs![Qty] = OrderQty
    rs![Operator] = AssyOps
    rs![Test Operator] = TestOps
    rs![Tester Used] = TestUnit
    rs![Test Time] = TestTime
    rs![Comments] = Comment
    rs![Status] = Status
    rs![Setup Time] = SetTime
    rs![Function] = Funct
    rs![Date] = LogDate
    rs![BOM Time] = BOMT
    rs.Update
        
    'Close the recordet and the connection.
    rs.Close
    con.Close
    
    'Release the objects.
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
    
    'Re-enable the screen.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'Inform the user that the macro was executed successfully.
    'MsgBox lastRow - 1 & " rows were successfully added into the '" & accessTable & "' table!", vbInformation, "Done"
    MsgBox "Write complete."
    
End Sub

Function FileExists(FilePath As String) As Boolean
 
    '--------------------------------------------------
    'Checks if a file exists (using the Dir function).
    '--------------------------------------------------
 
    On Error Resume Next
    If Len(FilePath) > 0 Then
        If Not Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileExists = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
 
End Function
```

Unfortunately though, when opening the database my new record has not been added.
I'm aware that this would be a lot easier to do directly in Access, but doing it this way will save us a lot of time as it will automate most of the process.

Comment: *runs without errors* - probably because you have `On Error Resume Next`. Add `On Error Goto 0` before `con.Open`

Comment: You did neither specify a table nor the connection for your recordset. See: [AddNew Method (ADO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/addnew-method-ado).